# Is "process" statement concurrent or sequential in nature?

Tags: vhdl

So i have looked around this exchange and other places too, but it has only increased the confusion..:(
Below are two links out of many which contribute to the confusion:

1.) [csee.umbc-states that process is a concurrent stmt](https://www.csee.umbc.edu/portal/help/VHDL/concurrent.html#bloc)

2.)[states process stmt as a sequential stmt](https://www.cse.usf.edu/%7Ehaozheng/teach/cda4253/doc/vhdl-stmt.pdf)

I am super confused as to how this could be reconciled.....
One theory i have is that VHDL is inherently concurrent and that process could be a way to make stmts sequential but they themselves are executed concurrently, but i don't get how two University guides could say entirely contradictory things...

Comment: Processes execute concurrently with one another. The statements within an individual process are executed sequentially.

Comment: "process could be a way to make stmts sequential but they themselves are executed concurrently", that is what i thought too but how can then second linked source classify "process" as a sequential statement.

Comment: AFAIK, there is no `process` statement in Verilog, so I have removed the Verilog tag. Even if there were a `process` statement in Verilog, its meaning would likely have nothing to do with the `process` statement in VHDL.

Comment: @AvisChaser a careful reading of the (first page of the) second reference shows that it's not classifying "process" as a sequential statement. It makes the explicit statement that "The sequential domain is represented by a process [...] that contains sequential statements" and that "The concurrent domain is represented by an architecture that contains processes[...]" Most importantly, it later makes the statement that "The process declaration delimits a sequential domain of the architecture [...]" Everything it says is correct, but yes the presentation lends itself to misunderstanding.

Answer (score 3):

Processes run concurrently with each other, as per comment above. So a process is a concurrent statement.

Within a process, statements **act as if** they execute sequentially. I stop short of saying they **execute** sequentially [because, nominally, they take zero time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13954193/is-process-in-vhdl-reentrant/13956532#13956532).

This also gets to the heart of the difference between signals and variables.

Within a process, use variables, and you are in the familiar world of sequential imperative programming, like C or Ada. Indeed you can translate simple programs directly into VHDL and expect them to work. (With Ada, very little translation required).

This may make inefficient hardware, requiring further translation to pipeline them or break them up into smaller steps rather than attempting to execute them in a single clock cycle, but this approach is fine for simulation e.g. to produce a golden model for your testbench, to compare against your actual hardware for correct results.

Signals are the inter-process communication mechanism. As such, their semantics are different to preserve determinism. The Q&A linked above describes how signal assignment works to prevent race conditions between processes.